# How to handle input data more than 2 dimension in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, svm

I'm learning the ml course these days. I found that the example input data is some like that (for example, malignant tumor classification):

```
/    size   gender    classification

m1  100     male      malignant

m2   50    female     benign
```

All these data can put into a m * n matrix, which m is the number of samples and n is the number of features.

What if the input data is not the form of row and column. For example, I want to predict if a customer is malicious by his order history. And the input data is in a form of:

I have multiple customers:

```
[c1, c2, c3]
```

A customer has multiple order:

```
[o1, o2, o3]
```

And each order has properties:

```
[orderDate, itemName. itemType, isPayed]
```

so I think I just can not put these data into a matrix. In a program code, it should be a three dimensional array.

How to deal with this kind of data?

Comment: For this kind of problem, I ideally I would use time series modelling. Check churn rate prediction problem and you might get some ideas.

Comment: Does the number of orders for each customer is same?

Comment: @ashwinids no, they are different

Comment: You can use Recurrent neural networks and it's variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a different model for each order. Each of them should output 0 if customer is not malicious based on that order and 1 otherwise. Then, use plurality vote in order to get your result.

Comment: Hi gdaras, you mean I should change my problem into malicious order prediction? em... Sounds a possible way to solve it

Comment: Yes. Actually you assume that each order category (orderName, itemName, etc) indicates independently whether the customer order is malicious. So the logic is that if a lot of order categories indicate that you are malicious, you probably are!

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the whole set of orders as a variable length time sequence, and perform classification/prediction on that sequence using a recurrent neural network.

e.g. the time steps for customer 1 may be o1, o2, o3 while customer 2 has o1, o2, o3, o4, o5.

Each time step has 4 feature dimensions (your order properties). The customer 1 full time sequence input would look like this (each column is a time step):

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| o1.orderDate | o2.orderDate | o3.orderDate | o4.orderDate |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| o1.itemName  | o2.itemName  | o3.itemName  | o4.itemName  |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| o1.itemType  | o2.itemType  | o3.itemType  | o4.itemType  |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| o1.isPaid    | o2.isPaid    | o3.isPaid    | o4.isPaid    |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Assuming the training data is labeled correctly, this setup will also discover fraud that has some sort of temporal dependency between events.

Take a look at this tutorial.

https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html